# data Type is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & JobsArrayProps'

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript, mapping

I got an Array of objects , each objects contain information of a job vacancy (id, title ,type, deadline) , i imported the Array to a functional component called Vacancies.tsx , in the this functional component i tried to map over the array to display the list of job vacancies by passing the data of each object through props into another component called (JobVacancy) as below ,

```
import { data } from "../data/JobVacancies";
import { JobsProps } from "../models/types.types";

const Vacancies: FC = () => {
  const [jobs, setJobs] = useState(data);

  return (
    <div className="w-screen h-min p-10 grid grid-cols-[1fr_3fr] justify-items-center bg-products-bg bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-cover ">
      <JobSearchForm />
      <div>
        {jobs.map((job) => {
          return <JobVacancy job={job} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

JobsProps  is the typescript i defined for the data as

```
export interface JobsProps {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  location: string;
  fullTime: boolean;
  deadline: Date;
}
```

the issue im having now im getting squiggly line under the prop (job) with a message

```
Type '{ job: { id: number; title: string; location: string; fullTime: boolean; deadline: Date; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & JobsArrayProps'.
  Property 'job' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & JobsArrayProps'. Did you mean 'Jobs'?ts(2322)
```

what could be the issue here , i appreciate your feedback.

edit:  below is the definition of  JobVacancy

```
const JobVacancy: FC = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="w-3/5 h-[10rem] px-5 z-10 grid grid-cols-[3fr_1fr] grid-rows-2 justify-items-center items-center shadow-lg shadow-neutral-900  bg-primary-100 ">
      <div>
        <h3 className="text-5xl text-secondary-200 flex items-center">
          <span className="text-3xl text-white rounded-full bg-blue-700 px-4 mr-2">
            1
          </span>
          Job Title
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div className="row-span-2">
        <button className="lgbt secondarybt uppercase">Apply</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h5 className="text-2xl">
          <span className="mx-1">Location</span>/
          <span className="mx-1">part Time</span>/
          <span className="mx-1">date</span>
        </h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Please post the definition of `JobVacancy` component too.

Comment: Done , not yet completed tho.

Comment: Based on your code, it seems that you don't have `job` prop exposed as object `JobVacancy`. So  invoke `JobVacancy` as `<JobVacancy {...job} />;` which will destructure the props.